# How to plot mean line of multiple lines using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I am working through an example creating a faceted plot using `ggplot`. The plot contains 4 `subplots`, each with multiple lines. How do you plot the mean line for each of the subplots? My attempt is shown below:

```
library(datasets)
data(ChickWeight)

library(ggplot2)
g = ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight))
g = g + geom_line(aes(group = Chick, color = Diet))
g = g + facet_grid(. ~ Diet)
g = g + stat_summary(aes(group = Diet), fun.y=mean, size = 1, color="black", geom="line")
g
```

I am unsure if I am using the `geom_summary` function correctly. I also tried `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)` but was unsure whether this output was the same as the mean.

Comment: Looks correct. If you would like a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) that site may be better suited to seek comments on the usefulness/efficiency of your code. Stack Overflow is designed for specific programming problems.

Comment: Thank you! I am slowly learning how to properly use this site.